# Javascript reference issue with copying

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a raw array which I initialize like this:

```
$scope.rawUsers = angular.copy($scope.users);
```

I then modify some data in like this:

```
function filterUsers(searchString, onlyMine) {

$scope.users = [];

_.find($scope.rawUsers, function (itm) {

    var groups = [];


    if (onlyMine) {
        if (!itm.IsMine)
            return;
        var hasGroup = false;
        _.find(itm.Groups, function (group) {



            if (lowercaseGroups.indexOf(searchString) != -1) {
                hasGroup = true;

                groups.push(group);
            }

        });

        if (hasGroup) {
            itm.Groups = groups;
            $scope.users.push(itm);
        }

    } else {
        if (itm.IsMine)
            return;

        $scope.users.push(itm);
    }

});


}
```

How do I fix it so that the original value is not lost?

Comment: consider using angular.copy : $scope.rawUsers = angular.copy($scope.users);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **spread syntax** like

```
$scope.rawUsers = [...$scope.users];
```

Which will give you a new copy of the array `$scope.users` without any reference.

> Spread syntax allows an iterable such as an array expression or string to be expanded in places where zero or more arguments (for function calls) or elements (for array literals) are expected, or an object expression to be expanded in places where zero or more key-value pairs (for object literals) are expected

For further reading visit [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

And if you want to use `angularjs` function then you can use `angular.copy()` as it creates a deep copy of source, which should be an object or an array. Which will be like:

```
$scope.rawUsers = angular.copy($scope.users);
```

Comment: I am trying angular.copy and it doesn't work, it still updates the groups in the main object

Comment: I have edited the code and shown more what I am doing

Comment: When I use var data = angular.copy($scope.rawUsers); inside the function then it works

Comment: @mohsinali1317 then use inside the function. What's the problem then?